# Retreated out of arm’s reach

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm trying to understand the exact meaning of this sentences, would you help me out please?

> One of the villagers gave bananas to two of the natives, wary of approaching him, as they quickly grabbed the fruit and ***retreated out of arm’s reach***.

[Source](https://www.newsinlevels.com/products/people-from-a-rainforest-level-3/#)

Comment: Took a step or two backwards so as not to be within the giver's reach.  We can be **out of arms's reach** or **out of harm's way** or **out of immediate danger**. They all mean different things, of course, but **out of** means "not within the specified zone".  *Get out of the way!*

Comment: "Arm's reach" is a catchphrase because it hardly ever refers to a particular individual's reach.  It really means far enough away to feel safe from being grabbed or hit.